# Keep or increment field value based on value of another field in arcpy

Tags: arcpy

My requirement is to create auto increment numbers in the `field2`  based on the values in `field1`. But if `field1` having same for more than one row, Increment number also remains same.

ex:

```
field1         |  field2
479049.620600  |  1  
479049.620600  |  1  
478611.065000  |  2  
478732.117500  |  3  
478890.969400  |  4  
478890.969400  |  4  
478890.969400  |  4  
479046.462900  |  5  
478576.747800  |  6
```

I have searched and got some code but it does not meet my requirement.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

path = r"C:\SOFTWARE\Shapefiles\shp\Points.shp"
arcpy.env = path

rows = arcpy.arcpy.UpdateCursor(path)
myList = []

i = 0

for row in rows:
    if i == 0:
        value = row.X
        myList.append(value)
    i += 1
    print value, i
    if row.ID != value:
        value = row.X
        myList.append(value)
    rows.updateRow(row)
del rows
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include details about what happens when you run your code snippet that you say doesn't meet your requirement.

Comment: Do you mean you want to increment `field2` based on the value in `field1` so if the value in `field1` already exists it reuses the same number for `field2`?

Comment: Yes Midavalo. if number in field1 exits two times, increment number also same.

Comment: Field1 field2(increment field)
152         1
145         2
145         2
125         3
125         3
178         4

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to include clarification or more info, rather than using comments.  Comments are for potential answerers to ask for more info, your response should be as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a python dictionary to store your `field1` values with the increment value entered into `field2` for that value.  In your cursor look up if the `field1` already has an increment value, and if it does use that value.  If it doesn't then use the increment `i` and add that to the dictionary.

```
import arcpy
i = 1
incDict = dict()
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(path , ["field1", "field2"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in incDict:
            row[1] = incDict[row[0]]
        else:
            row[1] = i
            incDict[row[0]] = i
            i += 1
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Note I've used the same numbers as your example, but not in the same order to show that the increment number will be reused when the `field1` value is reused.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you Midavalo. it helps me a lot and save the time also.